# issue: Not able to generate grpc.pb.h and grpc.pb.cc files

Tags: grpc, out

tried below command:

```
C:\UAproto\Source\OSS\grpc\tools>protoc -I=C:/UAproto/Source/Self/Auth/proto/ --grpc_out=C:/UAproto/Source/Self/Auth/Common/ --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`C:/UAproto/Source/OSS/grpc/tools/grpc_cpp_plugin.exe` C:/UAproto/Source/Self/Auth/proto/hUSAuth.proto
```

and getting error as:

```
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Any suggestion how to proceed?

How to generate all four files: grpc.pb.h, grpc.pb.cc, pb.h and pb.cc, with Visual studio 2017, cpp application